# Qt portable IPC: only QSharedMemory?

Tags: c++, qt, ipc, message, platform-independent

I'm looking for suggestions about choosing a portable way to achieve local IPC in a robust way, since i'm new to C++ and would like to avoid common pitfalls of fiddling with shared memory and locks; therefore I was thinking about message-passing style ipc.

I was planning to use qt for other reasons anyway, thus i took a peek to Qt ipc options.

if i understand correctly qt doesn't offer a completely portable message-passing ipc feature. it can use d-bus, but using it on windows would be a problem. other ways are limited to embedded linux platforms (and i would like to port this thing to AIX).

I could not find a "signal and slots" or message-passing style implementation that uses QSharedMemory and QSystemSemaphores

Thus: Am I limited to implement a feature on QSM/QSS? 
what other options could i study?
posix pipes? protocol buffers? boost queues and messages ?

I'm considering to release the code under LGPL/GPL style license, does this rule out protocol buffers or boost libs?

please, again, the interface must be simple and newbie-proof (otherwise i definitely will screw up things big time for sure :) ), and so should the serialization/deserialization of types, error handling and resource disposal.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but try QLocalSocket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) which provides a lot of IPC functionality.  I have used the interprocess [message_queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue) that provides a pretty clean and easy way to do what I think you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QLocalSocket](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qlocalsocket.html) and [QlocalServer](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qlocalserver.html) for IPC too.
Those two classes are really easy to use and they can be implemented ~almost the same way as you would using Qt TCP socket client/server.

You can take a look at some of these youtube videos:

[QTCPServer - a basic TCP server application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSdKkZNEKlQ)

[QTcpServer using multiple threads](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKtCXUHsV70)

(Almost the sames principles would apply for "Local" server/client instead of "TCP")

Answer (score 0):

As Qt 5.9, there is module which is currently under technology preview name [QtRemoteObjects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html) which provides Qt native IPC for QObjects, its easy to use and could be used to share signal/slots and also models between two processes.

Its works well for Linux, Windows and android