# Passing information between two seperate programs

Tags: c++, linux, ipc

I want to pass a value of an input variable in my program lets say#1 to another program #2 and i want #2 to print the data it got to screen, both are needed to be written in c++. The this will be on Linux.

Comment: that's what IPC (Inter-Process Communication) is for :)

Comment: @cadthecoder For questions like this, you should always mention the platform you are on. From one of your comments, I see you mention Linux, so I have tagged this accordingly - in future, please do this yourself.

Comment: Sure Im new here, but I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment to Roopesh Majeti's answer, here's a very simple example using environment variables:

First program:

```
// p1.cpp - set the variable
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;;    
int main() {
    _putenv( "MYVAR=foobar" );
    system( "p2.exe" );
}
```

Second program:

```
// p2.cpp - read the variable
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

int main() {
    char * p = getenv( "MYVAR" );
    if ( p == 0 ) {
        cout << "Not set" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Value: " << p << endl;
    }
}
```

Note:

- there is no standard way of setting an environment variable
- you will need to construct the name=value string from the variable contents

Comment: This is perfect for me. Thank you all for help.

Comment: Just remember that environment variables will imply a parent/child relationship between the processes. In this case piping stanard input/output is also another simple solution and also a standard unix way of sharing data.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the platform there are a number of options available. What you are trying to do is typically called inter-process communication (IPC).

Some options include:

- Sockets
- Pipes
- Queues
- Shared Memory

What is easiest is probably dependent on the platform youa are using.

Comment: This operation will take place on a GNU/Linux distro. Which way will be more efficient.

Comment: The most efficient way is most likely to be shared memory. I would follow @Space_C0wb0y advice and use a higher level library like Boost. This would simplify the problem for you.

Comment: Efficiency is unlikely to be that important, despite newbies thinking that it is. Shared memory can be difficult to luse, and I would personally go for  a socket-based solution. The use of libraries, boost or otherwise, is of course a good idea.

Comment: Named Pipes is nothing that i am looking for, but boost would be ok i will go through its documents.

Comment: @cadthecoder: Named pipes seem like the best solution: they are reasonably efficient, easy to use, low overhead, and quite portable (POSIX). Why add the extra bloat that comes with a template library like Boost? It's completely unnecessary to solve the problem at hand. Named pipes would be *the* canonical solution on Linux (or any Unix variant, really), IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

As always, there is a [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) for that (God, I like Boost).

Answer (score 5):

Nic has covered all the 4 that I wanted to mention (on the same machine):

- Sockets
- Pipes
- Queues
- Shared Memory

If writing system calls is troublesome for you, you may want to use the following libraries:

1. Boost http://www.boost.org/
2. Poco http://pocoproject.org/blog/
3. Nokia Qt http://qt.nokia.com/

Something you can read from [Qt portable IPC: only QSharedMemory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717540/qt-portable-ipc-only-qsharedmemory)

Answer (score 2):

If effeciency is not prime concern then use **normal file i/o**.

else go for IPC to do so.

As far as **Windows** is concern you have following options :

Clipboard ,
COM ,
Data Copy ,
DDE ,
File Mapping ,
Mailslots ,
Pipes ,
RPC ,
Windows Sockets

For **Linux** , use can use **Name Pipes**(efficient) or **sockets**.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, you can use Microsoft Message Queueing. This is an example of queue mentioned previously.

Answer (score 1):

If the data to be passed is just a variable, then one of the option is to set it as Environment Variable [ Var1 ] by program #1 and access it, in Program #2 [ if both are running on same env/machine ]. Guess this will be the easiest one, instead of making it complex, by using IPC/socket etc.

Comment: This would be easy, but will only work if the program setting the variable creates the process reading it.

Comment: Yes Neil. You are right. I take my statement back. Sorry for that. But i guess, we can kick off prog2 from prog1, in this case,  if both are not required to run parellely. Please correct me, if am wrong.

Comment: Ok well its possible to kick off p#2 from p#1 how will this environment variable work.

Comment: The following code snippet might help you :

   #include <iostream>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
         putenv("T1=R");
         system("checkenv");
    }

   checkenv.cc
   -----------
   #include <iostream>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
      cout <<  getenv("T1") << endl;
   }

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the answers have address the common IPC mechanisms. I'd just like to add that I would probably go for sockets because it's fairly most standard across several platforms. I decided to go for that when I needed to implement IPC that worked both on Symbian Series 60 and Windows Mobile.

The paradigm is straightforward and apart from a few platform glitches, the model worked the same for both platforms. I would also suggest using Protocol Buffers to format the data you send through. Google uses this a lot in its infrastructure. http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Answer (score 1):

- DBUS
- QtDbus
- DBus-mm

Answer (score 0):

For a very dirt and completely nonprofessional solution you can do it like me.

Save the variable in to a file and then read it (in an infinite loop every x time) with the other program.

```cpp
fsexample.open("F:/etc etc ...");
fsexample >> data1 >> data2; // etc etc
```

and on the other side

```cpp
fsexample.open("F:/etc etc ...");
fsexample << data1 << data2; // etc etc
```

The trick is that `F` is a virtual drive created with ramdisk so it is fast
and heavy-duty proof.

You could have problem of simultaneous access but you can check it with

```cpp
if (!fsexample.is_open()) {
    fsexample_error = 1;
}
```

and retry on failure.

Comment: It would be great if you could either give more detailed instructions on using ramdisk or point to another resource (SO answer) doing so.