# Getting a value of a textfield from another application in Qt C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ipc

I am just wondering is there a way to get 
the value of a textfield from another 
application?

Windows OS

For example in window a textbox2 has a value of 1.

How would i get the value of textbox2 from another application then?

Comment: @Andro: please tag question appropriately

Comment: This question is impossible to answer; It depends on OS, what the "other application" is and what you mean by "textfield".

Comment: Are both programs Qt? Are you able to change the other program too?

Comment: No the other program was made from Foxpro its actually a POS application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on [IPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You should be able to find a solution on that webpage that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to send information between to applications there are a number of ways to do it. Depends entirely on you circumstances. Why don't you try a search here on SO? There are many related questions:

[Passing information between two seperate programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920687/passing-information-between-two-seperate-programs)

Elaborate your question or search for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows APIs to get the handle of the target window and get its text. Look for 
[FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500.aspx) or [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497.aspx) Win32 APIs for this purpose.

Remember that this solution only works for Windows you can not port it to Linux!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a generalized solution that will work between two applications across different platforms and machines (i.e. Window 1 is on a Windows PC, Window 2 is on a Linux PC), check out [libQxt and it's IPC classes](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/tech-ipc.html).  Specifically, you might want to look at [QxtRPCPeer](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxtrpcpeer.html).